Expected value of the random variable: $\int (\mu + \sigma Z)\phi(x)dZ$
There is a random variable $X$ and its standard normal viariable $Z = \dfrac{X-\mu}{\sigma}$.
I'm looking for an expected value of the random walk defined by $V = \mu + \sigma Z$. For $X \in [0, \infty)$.
$$\int\limits_{-\mu/\sigma}^{\infty}(\mu + \sigma Z) \phi(Z)dZ = \mu(1-\Phi(\mu / \sigma)) + \sigma \phi(\mu / \sigma)$$
The results of integration are taken from List of integrals of Gaussian functions.
My concern is that in the answers the first term is just $\mu \Phi(\mu / \sigma)$, which is likely to be false, given that $\mu$ should have high "weight" in the final result. Am I doing it right? or am I missing sth?

$$
\begin{split}
\mathbb{E}[\mu + \sigma Z] &= \int_{-\mu / \sigma}^{\infty} (\mu + \sigma z) \phi(z)dz \\
&= \mu \int_{-\mu / \sigma}^{\infty} \phi(z)dz + \sigma \int_{-\mu / \sigma}^{\infty} z\phi(z)dz \\
&= \mu \bigg(1-\int_{-\infty}^{-\mu / \sigma}\phi(z)dz\bigg) + \sigma \phi(\mu / \sigma) \\
&= \mu (1 - \Phi(-\mu / \sigma)) + \sigma \phi(\mu / \sigma) \\
&= \mu \Phi(\mu / \sigma) + \sigma \phi(\mu / \sigma)
\end{split}
$$
where in the last term I used the fact that by simmetry $\Phi(x) + \Phi(-x) = 1$
